# Full Text Search always returns empty result set

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, fulltext-index

I have a table named 'fact' with title column, that should be full text index.

Firstly, I add a full text index:

```
ALTER TABLE fact ADD FULLTEXT title_fts (title)
```

So, I insert row:

```
INSERT INTO fact (id, title) VALUES ('1', 'red blue yellow ok green grey ten first wise form');
```

And then I perform search:

```
select * from fact f where contains (f.title, '"red" or "blue"')
```

When I perform the following query, or any other query with 'contains' statement, I get emtpy result set:

I have to use this statement, **not** against-match or like.
Does anyone happen to have an idea why is this happening?
Thank you.

Comment: Thats not full text search you need to use `match against` syntax

Comment: You are completely right. That solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two *really* important concepts when using full text search.  The first is the minimum work length (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)).  By default, the value is 4, meaning that words shorter than this are ignored.  Bye-bye "red", "ok", "ten" and other short words.

The second important concept is the stop words list (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)).  This would also get rid of "ok" and "first".

Your text doesn't have "blue" and "red" is ignored, so your query doesn't return anything.

You will need to re-build your index after you decide on the words that you really need to include.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But, when I do the same things with the (only) 5-letter words, that is: select * from fact f where contains (f.title, 'green or yellow'), I still get the empty result set. Should full text index be reconfigured?

Comment: @YoungDev . . . You also need to learn about boolean mode versus natural language mode.  The structure of your queries suggests that you should stick to boolean mode.